# How can i display a map (map-built save in bag file) with hector slam on android mobile app?

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a newbie in ros. I success to run hector using RpLidar (A1) and raspberry pi 3. I saved the data i had received in my bag file. How can i display this map on android mobile app ? Can someone give me some suggests ? Tks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287831/how-can-i-display-a-map-(map-built-save-in-bag-file)-with-hector-slam-on-android-mobile-app?/) by [Cynd1204](https://answers.ros.org/users/34494/cynd1204/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on 2018-04-08**:
[android_apps/map_nav](https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps/tree/kinetic/map_nav/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava/android_apps/map_nav)
that might help

**Comment by [Cynd1204](https://answers.ros.org/users/34494/cynd1204/) on 2018-04-12**:
Tks for your help. Can you please give me the name og activity you use to show the map for me ? Thanks a lot. And how you send it from PI3 or some thing like PI3 to android app? Would you mind show me step-by-step tutorial for this. i owned you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have never try it in PI3 but I did it between my ubuntu16.04 and my android phone.
There is a OccupancyGridLayer at line 160 in this  [activity](https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps/blob/kinetic/map_nav/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava/android_apps/map_nav/MainActivity.java)
change the mapTopic to yours and rosbag play your bag

---

Originally posted by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) with karma: 138 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cynd1204](https://answers.ros.org/users/34494/cynd1204/) on 2018-04-16**:
so you use PC to connect with your app and send data to the mobile ??? i see the line 160 , but i dont understand you use what to connect your PC with the app , can you show me ? Tks a lot.